# Sorted Pagination on Composite Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

I have ElasticSearch 7.1 documents with following mappings:-

```
{
  "event" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Code1" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "Code2" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "Date1" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "Date2" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "Value" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to group the documents by `Code1`, `Code2`, `Date1`, `Date2` into buckets
together with

`TotalValue` which is sum of `Value` field of all documents in a bucket

and

`Count` which is number of documents in a bucket.

Final Output which I want is like this:-

```
{
    {
        "Code1": "ABC",
        "Code2": "XYZ",
        "Date1": "01/01/2022",
        "Date2": "31/01/2022",
        "TotalValue": "100",
        "Count": "3"
    },
    ...
}
```

Also I want, paginated output with sorting on any of the output fields of the bucket, viz. ; `Code1`, `Code2`, `Date1`, `Date2`, `TotalValue`, `Count`.

Using Composite Aggregation, I came up with this query, which is able to do aggregation as reqd with paginated response and sorting on `Code1`, `Code2`, `Date1`, `Date2`

but not able to do proper sorted pagination on `TotalValue`and `Count`(doc_count) fields.

```
GET event/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
      "AggregatedBucket": {
        "composite": {
          "size":"10",
          "sources": [
           {
              "Code1": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "Code1",
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            },
           {
              "Code2": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "Code2",
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "Date1": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "Date1",
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "Date2": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "Date2",
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "aggs":{
            "TotalValue":{
              "sum": {
                "field": "Value"
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}}
```

Here is the truncated response I am getting

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "AggregatedBucket" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "Code1" : "ABC2",
        "Code2" : "XYZ2",
        "Date1" : "02/01/2022",
        "Date2" : "02/02/2022"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "Code1" : "ABC1",
            "Code2" : "XYZ1",
            "Date1" : "01/01/2022",
            "Date2" : "01/02/2022"
          },
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "TotalValue" : {
            "value" : 4.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "Code1" : "ABC2",
            "Code2" : "XYZ2",
            "Date1" : "02/01/2022",
            "Date2" : "02/02/2022"
          },
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "TotalValue" : {
            "value" : 3.0
          }
        }
     ]
   }
 }
```

Any alternate way to return my expected response would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say this, but you cannot paginate a composite aggregation using a sort order. The composite aggregation is already "sorted" based on the keys that you specified for the pagination.
In your case it will sort

1. On ascending order of Code1
2. If 2 code1's are the same, then ascending order of Code2
3. If 2 code2's are the same, then ascending order of Date1
4. If 2 Date1's are the same, then ascending order of Date2.

The subaggregation that you have created (total) cannot be used to sort a composite aggregation.

This is and always has been a major drawback of composite aggregations.

If you want to make this less complicated, a simpler way would be to build a concatenated field out of the four fields:
"Code1-Code2-Date1-Date2". THen insert that into every document. Perform a terms aggregation on the concatenated field and sort in descending order (which will automatically be your "total"). This still does not allow you to paginate, but you can set the size of the returned aggregation response to something that is large enough to meet your requirement.

Aggregations have very poor support for pagination. They are actually intended to take ALL the data in the index and produce a response. The concept of pagination is not designed around aggregations.

HTH.